# S3 temporary URLs for Bucket Contents without Key Information

Tags: amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am using the code below to return temporary URLs for files in an S3 bucket that are displayed on my website.

```
export function PreURL(IAM_USER_KEY, IAM_USER_SECRET, BUCKET_NAME, Key1) {
    let s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
        endpoint: 's3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com',
        signatureVersion: 'v4',
        region: 'us-west-1',
        accessKeyId: IAM_USER_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: IAM_USER_SECRET,
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME
    });
    var params = {Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, Key: Key1, Expires: 60};
    var url = s3bucket.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
    console.log('Image The URL is', url); // expires in 60 seconds
    return url.toString()
} // End of PreURL
```

It returns a URL along these lines:

https://**BUCKET**.s3-**REGION**.amazonaws.com/**FILE**?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=**IAM_KEY**%2F20200909%2F**REGION**%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=**TIME**&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Signature=**SIGNATURE**&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=**HEADERS**#t=0.1

This URL troubles me somewhat as it gives away everything but the secret_access_key. I know that the bucket cannot be accessed without it but I would prefer a temporary URL without so much information in it. (Bucket_Name, .amazonaws, IAM_KEY). Is there any other way of creating a temporary URL for files in an S3 bucket that does not give away so much information?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no facility to create an 'alias' for objects.

I understand that you are worried that it is showing your Bucket and Key values, but this is the normal way that pre-signed URLs operate.

If you *really* don't like what it is doing, then you could:

- Copy the files to a 'random' Key
- Provide the pre-signed URL for the temporary object
- Use a Lifecycle Policy to delete the objects after 1 day

Comment: Thank you very much, although I am more concerned about the Bucket and IAM information than the file key.